# automapper with pagedlist always return one page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, pagedlist

I have 9 items in my database but after map items total count of item is pageSize and always pager show one page.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? page)
{
    int pageSize = 3;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

    var result = db.Projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDate);
    var model = result.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
    var model2 = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<PagedList<ProjectViewModel>>(model);
     return View(model2);

}

public class PagedListConverter : ITypeConverter<PagedList<Project>, PagedList<ProjectViewModel>>
{
    public PagedList<ProjectViewModel> Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var model = (PagedList<Project>)context.SourceValue;
        var vm = model.Select(m => Mapper.Map<Project, ProjectViewModel>(m)).ToList();

        return new PagedList<ProjectViewModel>(vm, model.PageNumber, model.PageSize);
    }
}
```

and in my automapper configuration i write down this

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Project, ProjectViewModel>();

Mapper.CreateMap<PagedList<Project>, PagedList<ProjectViewModel>>().ConvertUsing<PagedListConverter>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use something like `AutoMapper` in conjunction with `PagedList`, you must manually create your paged list with `StaticPagedList`, instead. That means you need to manually limit your queryset and get the total count yourself as well. For example:

```
int pageSize = 3;
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

var result = db.Projects.OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDate).Skip(pageSize * (pageNumber - 1)).Take(pageSize);
var totalResults = db.Projects.Count();
var model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<ProjectViewModel>>(result);
var model2 = new StaticPagedList<ProjectViewModel>(model, pageNumber, pageSize, totalResults);
return View(model2);
```

This does mean making two queries (one to select the items for the page and another to get the total count), but count queries are relatively quick. Regardless, that's the only way to do paging *and* map to another class type via `AutoMapper`.